# What does "Greeting Master" mean?

Tags: ever-oasis

In *Ever Oasis* I had talked to a number of the noots and eventually it said I have achieved "Greeting Master". I don't see this on any of my menu screens, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just held my first festival and afterwards the villagers built me a statue in the empty garden area near the entrance, then the game prompted info about statues and achievements. I'm fairly certain those messages are tied to the statues you get.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings master means you have greeted every noot! I know this because I got the achievement a long time ago
After completing your first festival it unlocks statues. Ever oasis is my favorite game ever!